# What is the pros and conts between JSOM and REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest, jsom

I have a dilemma choosing between JSOM and REST what is better? what are the pros and conts of both? is different in performance?

I have search but I cant find something usefull.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this session by David Mann (@mannD) from the Microsoft Developer Conference 2014: [Deep dive: REST and CSOM comparison](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC423).

[image]

Comment: I also cover the two topics in great deal in my Pluralsight course if you happen to have a subscription

Comment: But he talk about CSOM no JSOM

Comment: JSOM is the JavaScript version of CSOM. David covers JSOM in the session.

Comment: ah ok thank you, what is your course in Pluralsight? and what do you prefer?

Comment: My course is entitled "SharePoint 2013 Development: Client Object Model and REST API". It talks about what the APIs are and how to use them. David's session compares the two APIs.

Comment: The video is very helpful!